# What is the difference between Windows 10 Virtual Desktop and a Virtual Machine

Tags: windows, virtual-machine

Microsoft announced the Windows 10 Virtual Desktop at the Ignite conference. From my understanding, this is hosted in Azure. My question is, what's the difference between Windows 10 Virtual Desktop and just having a Windows Virtual Machine in Azure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is practically the same. The biggest difference will be that the Virtual Desktop environment is using features of Microsoft that other Virtual Machine software won't have, including Windows Store integration, but on the other hand, it will be more limited in what it can do.

Don't forget, Microsoft also has Hyper-V and Docker support, which is somewhat the same thing, but running from a different perspective.

There is however too little information to have a proper side-by-side comparison at this point.

Comment: I believe I read that Virtual Desktop, will use VDI (Virtual Desktop Instance) licensing, and is entire purpose is to provide remote desktop licensing options and they are indeed VMs.  Which means it would have the same requirements as Hyper-V.  The obvious difference, at the end of the day, would be the ability to access them as a remote desktop.